# Clearcase: cleartool mount vob in unix

Tags: unix, clearcase

Could someone provide me with an example on how to mount a vob (dynamic vob) onto a unix box. The view has already been created in windows.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use [`cleartool mount`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mount.htm):

```
cleartool mount /vobs/aVob
```

(as described in "[To mount/activate VOBs](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/to_activate_vob.htm)")

Note that you don't have to start a dynamic view: you can mount vobs even without any view.

But once that vob is mounted, it will be visible for **every** started dynamic views, **even the ones which doesn't use that vob** (doesn't use because their config spec doesn't select anything from the mounted vob).

```
cleartool mount /vobs/aVob
/views/aView_1/vobs/aVob
/views/aView_2/vobs/aVob
/views/aView_3/vobs/aVob
```

Comment: I up-voted this, but it needs a little more info. Mine would not mount because I didn't know the path. You need to find the properties of a vob and use it as an example.

Comment: What version of ClearCase are you using? Are you using multi-site? On what OS do you want to execure ClearCase commands like unlock?

Comment: No idea, I just use it as a client on Windows. I was simply saying I can't use `cleartool mount /vobs/vob_name`, I have to say `cleartool mount \vob_name` (forward-slash might work).

Comment: I agree: on Windows, the Vob tag starts with \, on Unix with /vobs/.